# Writing assembly code for the .Net platform

Tags: c#, assembly

I'm a seasoned C# developer who wants, for fun, to write a bit of assembly code. I was wondering if it was easiest simply to write in byte code and somehow use the C# compiler, linker whatever. I'm a bit unsure on how to go about this.

Or maybe there is a decent assembly language out there with a step debugger and other nice things shipped in an environment that I should pick up instead?

I mainly want to write code to do calculations and output to the console window.

Comment: Can you clarify your question a bit? Are you talking about CLR IL or  assembly language?

Comment: I guess I'm meaning IL when I write assembly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write it in MSIL and assemble it via the MSIL assembler (**[ilasm.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/496e4ekx.aspx)**).

As for a debugger, I've previously used [DILE](http://sourceforge.net/projects/dile/) (DotNet IL Editor) to step through IL code, <s>it's a bit out-dated though</s>.

Seems that DILE is still being updated, check out the [weekly builds](http://sourceforge.net/projects/dile/files/DILE/WeeklyBuild/).

Comment: I should mention that it's not fully fledged, it's more of a really simple debugger that you can use to step through code. Nothing too fancy.

Comment: @Carlo It seems that the project is still maintained, and there are weekly builds in the project files, you could check those out.

Answer (score 6):

You can write IL code and compile it with [ILASM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/496e4ekx.aspx)

Comment: cheers, so I should compile the 'hello world' example from your link and just insert my own code in the place where the content of the Main() is generated? Are there any options for step-execution of my programs?

Comment: I don't know if there are any IL level debuggers... perhaps .NET Reflector Pro can do it, but I'm not sure

Answer (score 3):

you can use assembly language of .net environment which is called CIL

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Intermediate_Language

Answer (score 2):

You can't use the C# compiler to write assembly code. However, you can you Visual Studio "CLR" projects which will compile native C/C++ with inline assembly blocks, which you can write a managed wrapper around so you can invoke via C#. See [CLI/C++ Tutorials](http://www.functionx.com/cppcli/index.htm) for more information.

You can also look at [masm32](http://www.masm32.com/) which you can use to write native x86 assembly libraries, then use p/invoke to execute them via C#.

Have fun!

Comment: Many thanks.. I think I prefer ilasm as if I ever disassemble a C# dll I sort of know what to expect.

Comment: @Carlos No worries, I think our definitions of "assembly language" are a bit different. Cheers, :)

Comment: I once wrote a java->286 assembly. It was pure horror. Eg. there were limitations on how far one could jump, so methods to compile could only grow to a certain size in number of instructions. That kind of suck I'd like to steer clear of.

Answer (score 0):

This may be helpful to others

As for editing MSIL, we can dump assembly file to IL file by the ILDASM utility and recompile it to assembly file by the ILASM utility,

The two utilities are included in the .NET SDK.

- C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 8\VC>ildasm .
- Open your assembly e.g. my.dll
- After opening the file, select File->Dump. Ensure all checkboxes are selected and then click OK.
  You will be prompted to save it as an IL file. I recommend creating a new directory to save as my.IL
- Open my.IL by your favourite editing tool (I use Visual Studio .NET 2005/2003).
- Edit your my.IL and then save it.
- C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 8\VC>ilasm /DLL X:\Folder\my.IL